# Laravel could not find driver (Alpine OS Docker)

Tags: php, laravel, docker, alpine-linux

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
ARG ALPINE_VERSION=3.16
FROM alpine:${ALPINE_VERSION}
# Setup document root
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install packages and remove default server definition
RUN apk add --no-cache \
  curl \
  nginx \
  php81 \
  php81-ctype \
  php81-curl \
  php81-dom \
  php81-fpm \
  php81-gd \
  php81-intl \
  php81-mbstring \
  php81-mysqli \
  php81-opcache \
  php81-openssl \
  php81-phar \
  php81-session \
  php81-xml \
  php81-xmlreader \
  php81-sodium \
  php81-xmlwriter \
  supervisor \
  php81-tokenizer \
  php81-pdo \
  php81-fileinfo

# Create symlink so programs depending on `php` still function
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/php81 /usr/bin/php

# Configure nginx
COPY docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Configure PHP-FPM
COPY docker/fpm-pool.conf /etc/php81/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY docker/php.ini /etc/php81/php.ini

# Configure supervisord
COPY docker/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Make sure files/folders needed by the processes are accessable when they run under the nobody user
RUN chown -R nobody.nobody /var/www/html /run /var/lib/nginx /var/log/nginx

# Switch to use a non-root user from here on
USER nobody

# Add application
COPY --chown=nobody . /var/www/html/

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
RUN cd /var/www/html && composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --ignore-platform-reqs

# Expose the port nginx is reachable on
EXPOSE 8080

# Let supervisord start nginx & php-fpm
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]

# Configure a healthcheck to validate that everything is up&running
HEALTHCHECK --timeout=10s CMD curl --silent --fail http://127.0.0.1:8080/fpm-ping
```

My Laravel app is being served, however when I get the following error trying to access it: `could not find driver` (QueryException, `select * from` sessions`where`id `= <id> limit 1`)
Here is my php.ini: https://pastebin.com/gHZevdw3 (too long for here).

I'm not too sure what needs to be done to enable PDO, or if my ini file is incorrect, but I'd appreciate some feedback on what can be improved.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You could also use a [php-alpine image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/tags?page=1&name=alpine).

Comment: I'm still getting used to Docker, so I'm not sure how I'd use nginx to serve my application from that base image

Comment: Nginx should run in another container.

Comment: I'm running this in a kube environment, so I do have a nginx controller. How does the container server the php application though?